# What is this large system volume information file?

Tags: windows-10, file-management, windirstat

I'm sure this is a repeat of a question someone has asked somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

There is just one file in my system system volume information folder that is taking up literally two-thirds of all the used space on the entire drive.

There are several different ways I could manually override the protections and delete the file, but before I resort to that, **is there any way to figure out what this file actually is?**

It shouldn't be a system restore or shadow copy thing, as my settings for that are still at the default ten gigabyte maximum.

Is it possible for file indexing to take up twice as much space as the stuff being indexed? If not, what else could it be?

I'm willing to just go ahead and delete the file manually, but I'd prefer to know what it is, and if there is any other way to manage it, before I do that.

Large file in system volume information:

[image: Large file in system volume information]

Just for background, I saw lots of unknown space using windirstat, then after a google search, ran treesize in admin mode to get more information.

All my google searches after that have been pretty fruitless, just telling me about things that usually take up space in system volume information, but don't seem to be the cause here, and a general warning that I probably shouldn't delete this manually, but it's just too big to ignore, so it needs to go.

However, if there's a good explanation, and a safe way to remove it, I'd like to pursue that first, before using a manual brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to figure out what this file actually is?

The System Volume Information folder contains (amongst other things):

> Disk snapshots made by [Volume Shadow Copy](https://%5BVolume%20Shadow%20Copy%20Service%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Learn%5D(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service)), which can be used to recover older versions of files. For each snapshot, a separate file is created with a long ID as a name

...

> [image]

Source: [How to Clean Up Large System Volume Information Folder on Windows? | Windows OS Hub](https://woshub.com/how-to-clean-up-system-volume-information-folder/)

The link includes detailed instructions on the correct way to clean up.

Comment: That article provided the answer, see below. H: is an external hard drive that's only plugged into my computer temporarily. No idea why windows decided that it was a good idea to let it use up most of my C: free space while it was around.

`Shadow Copy Storage association
   For volume: (H:)\\?\Volume{a14a2f38-2d86-4fd7-b82f-a716e8d5329f}\
   Shadow Copy Storage volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{94d2a7d3-a8ab-40c6-aa02-85c07608c7b3}\
   Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 286 GB (60%)
   Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 287 GB (60%)
   Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: UNBOUNDED (3623183471%)`